# spring cloud config environment repository has a database?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-connectors

**History**

I have application to get the dependencies program sources from front-end ( includes js, jsp, other RIA application files) to back-end ( includes java classes, table, columns). For analyzing this, I have to analyze each project develop architecture and configure many properties.

Each time I adapt my program to each project, I had to spend a lot of time to make configuration for customizing to each project. Also, it took long time for making the configuration. But, finally I accumulated so many environment sets after the adaption to many projects. So I want to gather this properties sets to the one repository and watch all thing in a web view and reuse them if I can find the similar one in the repository.

**Motivation & Implementation**

Yesterday I got good idea suddenly right after I saw about Spring Cloud Config.
Besides, I was changing the source of properties from the properties file to the database. And I will make the web  view for managing the database.

**Question**

- First : To connect the spring cloud config to the database, I need the data-source connector of spring cloud config. But I can't find that.
- Second : I will gather all kinds of properties into one repository. Is it a good idea? If you have this experience, Please share your insight or know-hows.

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: any update on this? I am looking as well for a way to hook up spring cloud config to a database

Comment: @K-RAD sadly, no.  I am still finding the way. If I finding,  I will share.  Sorry

Comment: There's an open issue here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/203  Pull requests welcome

Comment: @spencergibb thanks for it. I will consider it..